# TCP vs Plugin interface. What is better?

Tags: gazebo-plugin

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

According to official documentation there are two ways for an interaction with a robot in simulation: TCP and Plugin interface.
What is better? Could you write pros and cons of each.
And what will be easier to integrate with real robot?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/3400/tcp-vs-plugin-interface.-what-is-better?/) by [Olzhas](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/409/olzhas/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 13 on 2013-07-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

The two ways of interaction are very different, and are designed to facilitate different use cases.

A plugin has direct access to the Gazebo internals through the C++ api. A plugin also runs in the same process as Gazebo.

Message passing does not have direct access to the C++ api, but it does allow you to run code in a separate process (or on a different machine) from Gazebo.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-07-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0